# Why am I getting fatal error from mysqli_result::free after the query succeeds?

Tags: php, mysql

Why does this function successfully execute the database query, yet still results in **Fatal error: Call to a member function free() on a non-object** ?

```
private function record_login()
{
    $user_id = $this->user_id;
    $time = time();
    $ip_address = $this->ip_address;

    $link = $this->db_connect();

    $query = "INSERT INTO login_log (user_id, login_time, ip_address)
                    VALUES ('$user_id', '$time', '$ip_address')";

    $result = $link->query($query);

    if (!$result) {
        $this->log_error(); // This function does NOT get called
    }

    $result->free();
    $link->close();     
    return true;
}
```

EDIT:
Here is the db_connect() function from above:

```
private function db_connect() 
{
    $link = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
        die(mysqli_connect_error());
    }  
    else {
        return $link;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably be passing the connection into the object instead of having the object create it.  Also, you should consider using exceptions instead of dying inside of a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select-querys returns resources, insert-querys dosn't.
you can only free resources

Comment: +1 But could use a bit more specificity.  In particular, mysqli::query returns a mysqli_result object (not a resource, strictly speaking) for any query that results in a result set being created (SELECT, SHOW, EXPLAIN, etc).